Converting Python byteArray to List of Integers for Writing to Bluetooth Characteristic in Flutter?
I'm using Python with the Bleak library to write a bytearray to a Bluetooth device characteristic. The bytearray I'm sending is
bytearray(b'3\x01\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f')

However, in Flutter, I'm using the flutter_blue_plus package, which expects a list of integers to write to a characteristic. For example,
await c.write([0x12, 0x34]) 

is used in Flutter to write. How can I convert the Python bytearray to a format suitable for the write method in Flutter?
Note: I've tried following in flutter, but in vain.
Wrote:
await c.write([3, 1, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31]);

Response:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Wrote:
await c.write([51, 1, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31],);

Responses:
[51, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50]
[238, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 231]

and the responses from the device in case of python-bleak were following:
bytearray(b'\x00\x04S\x08')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04S\t')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04S\t')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04S\x08')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O\x1f')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O"')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O"')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O\x1f')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O ')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O\x1f')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O ')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O!')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O ')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O ')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O!')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O#')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O$')
bytearray(b'\x00\x04O%')


Use list() on the bytearray.

@MarkTolonen it looks like he already did that. His second call to c.write uses the output of list(bytearray(...))

What's the significance of the responses? Where do they come from?

@Joooeey Or OP typed it manually. Just pointing it out.
